# Couldn't post values to program

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am trying to POST text values to the different python program based on user selection (through radio button). Program works fine with single form action

```
<form action='/cgi-bin/prog1.py' method='POST'>
    ...text input1
    ...text input2
    ...submit

</form>
```

but when using radio button text values are not posted to the program.

Here is the code I tried

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
 <head>
  <title></title>
  <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
  <script type="text/javascript">
  function whichsite(form){
    var sites = form.elements.site, i = sites.length;
    while (--i > -1){
    if(sites[i].checked){
        return sites[i].value;
        }
    }
  }
  </script>
 </head>
 <body>
  <form action="#" onsubmit="window.open(whichsite(this)); return false; method='POST' ">
  <b>Program Jump</b>
  <p>
  Enter PDB ID:<input type="text" name="PDB_ID"><br>
  Enter PDB Chain:<input type="text" name="Chain_ID"><br>
  <label><input type="radio" name="site" value="/cgi-bin/prog1.py">P-P</label>
  <label><input type="radio" name="site" value="/cgi-bin/prog2.py">P-L</label>
  <label><input type="radio" name="site" value="/cgi-bin/prog3.py">P-C</label>
  <p>
  <input type="submit" value="Submit">
  </form>
 </body>
</html>
```

Help me !

Comment: Is the misplaced closing `"` for your `onsubmit` attribute just a typo in the question? (I assume you didn't intend `method='POST'` to be within the attribute, because it's after the `return`...)

Comment: @nnnnnn `onsubmit="window.open(whichsite(this))" ; return false; method='POST' >`  is actioning to '#'. Not moving to program mentioned in radio button. I hope that is correct. If not could you please explain?

Comment: Why is `method='POST'` *inside* the `onsubmit` attribute? (And what do you think `this` is in `whichsite(this)`? It'll be the form element...)

Comment: @nnnnnn POSTing the values to the program instead of `action='#'`.

Comment: That `method='POST'` won't be exeucted, because it is *after* `return false`.

Comment: `<form action="" onsubmit="window.(whichsite(this)); return false;">` is alos not working. URL becomes like this on submit `http://localhost/My_folder/radi.html?PDB_ID=1acb&Chain_ID=I&site=%2Fcgi-bin%2Fprog1.py`

Answer (score 0):

I think you should change the `action` attribute value of the form  in `onsubmit` method instead of `window.open` method, you can try something like this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>


<title></title>
  <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
  <script type="text/javascript">
  function whichsite(form){
    var sites = form.elements.site, i = sites.length;
    while (--i > -1){
    if(sites[i].checked){
        // here change the action value instead of return the site
        form.action = sites[i].value;
        }
    }
  }
  </script>
 </head>
 <body>
  <form action="#" onsubmit="whichsite(this); return false;" method="POST">
  <b>Program Jump</b>
  <p>
  Enter PDB ID:<input type="text" name="PDB_ID"><br>
  Enter PDB Chain:<input type="text" name="Chain_ID"><br>
  <label><input type="radio" name="site" value="/cgi-bin/prog1.py">P-P</label>
  <label><input type="radio" name="site" value="/cgi-bin/prog2.py">P-L</label>
  <label><input type="radio" name="site" value="/cgi-bin/prog3.py">P-C</label>
  <p>
  <input type="submit" value="Submit">
  </form>
 </body>
</html>
```

Or, you can try change the value of `action` in the `change` event of radio, hope this can help~~~